# Load tsv into html as var using d3.tsv

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I'm really newbie for front-end js/html/css

Basically I'd like to load .tsv as `var` in index.html; (my tsv and index.html are within the same folder in my github)

So first I should figure out how to "load" :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Loading data from server</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.2/d3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(data) {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=data;
    });
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

But this result in errors: `undefined`
My webpage has nothing but just `undefined`

What's the problem?
Also if I'd like to define var, what should I do?
Simply `var = data` ?

Comment: It sounds like your data is actually not being pulled through correctly. Are you sure you have a valid .tsv file? Perhaps copying the data has given you spaces instead of tabs, or similar.

Comment: Please check the browser console, where data.tsv file is loading or you are receiving some error or may be cross origin issue. Same code I ran it's working fine in Mozilla Firefox.